# how can I transfer downloaded movies to a usb?

Tags: usb-drive

I always download movies from torrents and have them on my laptop. Now I was trying to transfer them to my USB so it won't take too much space. Once I connected my USB to my TV the movies are not there? What am I doing wrong? So far the only thing I've done is just drag the movie to the USB.

Answer (score 3):

Three things you need to make sure that they exist, to be able to watch movies from your USB drive on your TV:

1. The USB drive needs to be in the correct format. eg Fat32 or ExFAT, check your TV’s manual for the supported format.
2. If the disc is in FAT32 format, then files can't be larger than 4GB each.
3. The movies need to be in a format recognized by your TV. eg. MPEG2 and MPEG4 are more than likely to be recognized, but for any other format, again, check your TV's manual.

Comment: Yes thats right, but you also have to firmware update your TV, settopbox or blyeray player, and even so there are a lot of dodgy / bogus codecs out there - that dont vork vit other devices!!